# How to save emails to a specific folder in drafts?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wrote Excel VBA code to generate emails from a report that is downloaded into Excel. It saves to the "drafts" folder in Outlook.

I want to save to another folder within drafts to keep them separate from my regular drafts.

This is what I have.

```
With objMail
    .To = rngTo
    .Subject = "Next 2 Weeks Orders"
    .HTMLBody = intro & vbNewLine & po & signiature
    .Save
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your code that actually creates `objMail`? Are you using `Application.CreateItem`? Use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` on a specific folder instead. Assuming "My custom subfolder" is a child folder of the Drafts folder:

```
set folder = objOutlook.Session.GetDefaulFolder(16) 'olfolderDrafts
set folder = folder.Folders("My custom subfolder")
set objMail = folder.Items.Add
```

Comment: '        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
 '

Comment: that is what I currently have

Comment: I am trying to incorporate what you suggested but I keep getting errors. Says that an object is required?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create new items in Outlook. If you need to save a new item to a specific folder in Outlook you choices are:

1. Create a new item using the `CreateItem` method and then use the `MoveTo` method to place the item to the target folder.
2. Use the `Items.Add` method which places new items to the folder where the `Items` collection comes from. For example:

```
nSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
targetFolder = nSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
folderItems = targetFolder.Items
mail = folderItems.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
```

You can find all these ways described with code samples in the [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/) article.